# GASを使用してメールを送信するとブロックされます。無料GMAILアカウントなら問題なく送信されます。

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

初心者です。何卒よろしくお願い致します。

GoogleAppScriptにてメールを送付したいのですが、以下のメッセージが契約しているアカウントのGmailに返ってきて、送付することができません。

> メールのブロック
> ○○@yahoo.co.jp へのメールはブロックされました。詳しくは、下記の詳細な技術情報をご覧ください。

以下のGASを実行しています。

```
function test() {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to:'●●●@yahoo.co.jp',
    subject:'テスト！',
    name:'自動送信メール',
    body:'これはテストです',
  })
}
```

同様の内容で、無料版の○○＠gmail.comにてGASを実行すると問題なく送付できます。
GoogleWorkplaceにて契約した有料アカウントでは送付することが出来ません。
試しに、有料アカウントのGMAILより同宛先に通常メール送付した場合は、問題なく送付できます。

GoogleWorkplaceのサポートに問合せしたところ、迷惑メールとしてみなされている可能性があるので
SPF設定を紹介していただき、実施しています。（これ以上は、サポートではわからないとのことでこちらを紹介していただきました。）
その後、Googleの以下の記事（https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=ja）
のとおりDKIM設定も設定し試してみましたが、同様のブロック状態になります。

唯一、実行してうまく送付されたのは、自分（有用アカウントメールアドレス）宛のメールです。
他Gmailアカウント向けもダメです。

なにか、試してみるべきことはありますでしょうか。

何卒よろしくお願いたします。

Answer (score 1):

権限が多少ゆるくなってしまうようですが、
MailAppではなくGmailAppを使うと、うまくいくことがあるようです。

Comment: 同じ事象になりましたが
こちらの対応で解決できました！
ありがとうございました！